# Error de CORS al consumir una API con jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Tengo que consumir una api y enviarle de datos un base64 que básicamente un XML cifrado pero obtengo el error del *CORS*. Ya investigue y esta relacionado con dominios o algo así pero no logro hacer que funcione, cabe destacar que al testear con *postman* si me funciona pero aquí no , la api es publica por lo cual no puedo modificar nada a nivel servidor o algo así alguien sabe como soluciono el error (omito la URL por seguridad):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://e' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "OMITO POR SEGURIDAD",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        CORS: true ,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType:'application/json',
        secure: true,
        headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        "apikey": "OMITO POR SEGURIDAD"
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(""));
        },
        data: {"nit_transmitter": "17664","xml_dte": base64},
        success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="validar ()"> validar</button>
</body>
```

Comment: El error de CORS es porque tu NAVEGADOR bloquea la solicitud por seguridad, por eso el Postman no da ese error. La solución es configurar el servidor donde está el API

Comment: pero yo no soy el dueño del servidor que puedo hacer ?

Comment: Cuando hiciste tu pregunta pusiste que estabas con PHP, asumiendo esto. Entonces debes crear un puente. tu javascript llama a un PHP tuyo, y este PHP llama a la otra API

Comment: Segun me dices deberia consumir la api desde php y luego llamarla en el script ?

Comment: Claro. Tu creas un PHP donde reciba por POST lo mismo que envías a la api, tomas esos dados y lo envías a esa API desde PHP, el api te va a retornar "algo", ese algo lo retornas como respuesta

Comment: YA NUNCA HE CONSUMIDO CON PHP PERO VOY A INTENTARLO

Comment: AUNQUE ME DA LA DUDA EN QUE SE DIFERENCIARIA HACERLO DESDE PHP O POR QUE AHI SI FUNCIONARIIA

Comment: Prueba investigando esta función file_get_contents y ojo no es necesario que hagas un parse o un decode, a ti lo que te llegue lo envías a al script (haces un echo $respuesta;). Sobre lo otro que pusiste, por supuesto que dudar no es malo, yo tampoco me fio de desconocidos. Perfectamente esto podría ser una venganza, ya que solo te dedicas a hacer preguntas y nunca tienes la gentiliza de responder a las respuestas que te ponen, ya sea para indicar que no te funcionó o para agradecer que si lo hizo y marcar la respuesta como aceptada